# Apache HttpComponents HttpContext behaves differently when domains differ after redirect

Tags: java, redirect, tomcat8, http-redirect, apache-httpcomponents

I made a a quite simple proxy to simulate an IAM. It works very simple by passing on requests to another server (the one that is proxied). I'm using apache HttpComponents. The server is TOMCAT 8 (the proxy too by the way).

Now I'm running into the following weird behaviour which I can't explain at the moment and I do hope that someone can help me out.

The code that delegates the request looks as follows:

```
BasicHttpContext context = getSessionToken(request);
dumpContext("before", context);
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpRequest, context);
dumpContext("after", context);
```

getSessionToken(request) gets the context from the session or it creates a new one and assigns it to the session, so that it can be passed with every request within the same session.

When the request is delegated to the same domain as the proxy, then everything works, but as soon as the domain differs, the session is lost. The JSESSIONID is not passed on (although I do see the sessionid in the cookie store).

This situation arises when the first call is followed by a redirect.

I made a dump of the context in case the domain is the same and when they differ

**domains are the same**

```
accept-language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4 
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br, 
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8,  
http.cookie-spec=default, 
http.cookie-store=[[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: AD4D19BB86D3333149A92A437A676D59][domain: localhost]  
[path: /ipAbnAmroContract][expiry: null]] 
http.target_host=http://localhost:8080,   
http.route={}->http://localhost:8080,   
http.cookie-origin=[localhost:8080/ipAbnAmroContract/],   
http.response=HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 303 See Other 
[Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AD4D19BB86D3333149A92A437A676D59; Path=/ipAbnAmroContract; HttpOnly,
```

**domains differ**

```
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5,                     
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate,           
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,             
http.cookie-spec=default, http.cookie-store=[[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: 87FD6DC8E528348DDA0A276D840C3070][domain: proxyserver]
[path: /ipAbnAmroContract][expiry: null]] 
http.target_host=http://proxyserver:8080, 
http.route={}->http://proxyserver:8080, 
http.cookie-origin=[proxyserver:8080/ipAbnAmroContract/], 
http.response=HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 303 See Other 
[Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=87FD6DC8E528348DDA0A276D840C3070; Path=/ipAbnAmroContract; HttpOnly
```

So in short: when the proxied server sent a session id (JSESSIONID) after a *direct redirect* it fails when the proxied server and the proxy are running on a domain **other** than *localhost*

The tested use cases are

1. proxy and proxied server both run on localhost
   **works**
2. proxied server does not run on local domain
   **fails**
3. both proxy and server do not run on local domain
   **fails**
4. proxy does not run localhost, the proxied server does
   **works**
5. without the initial redirect
   **works in all above mentioned used cases**
6. synchronizing access to context (thank you oleg)
   **has no effect on the outcome**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are HttpContext instances being accessed concurrently by multiple threads?

Comment: Not very sure, but this could very well be the case. If that might be a problem, then I do not understand why it works without redirects, assuming that in that case the same context is also accessed by multiple threads

Comment: Just tested your idea by synchronizing the access to the token within the critical section it can actually change. It does not solve the problem.

Comment: @oleg the problem only arises after a _direct redirect_ from the server. When I would run it within 'localhost' domain, then it works, it only fails when the proxied server is not located at localhost.

Comment: (1) Synchronizing access to HttpContext instance is not enough. HttpContext may _NOT_ be shared by multiple threads. Multiple HttpContext instances however may share thread-safe attributes such as auth cache, cookie store, credentials provider, etc

Comment: (2) Unless a cookie has a domain attribute set on it it will not be passed to another host other than the host of origin